# Не могу запустить программу для телеграмм бота на python. Возникает ошибка: AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'telebot'

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Возникает ошибка: AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'telebot'
А вот и сам код:

```
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.telebot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

#RUN
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы опечатались. Вам нужен класс `TeleBot`.

***Пример:***

```py
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)
#             ^^^^^^^
```